# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error when using association name in .where method instead of foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We just updated our Rails App from 3.0.13 to 3.2.6 and have encountered a minor problem when using the .where method of the Active Record Query Interface with mysql2.

What used to work before:

```
client = Client.first
User.where(:client => client)
```

now leads to:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
>   'users.client' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE
>   `users`.`client` = 1

But when explicitly using the column name of the foreign key, it seems to work just fine:

```
client = Client.first
User.where(:client_id => client.id)
#=> Relation of users with the given client_id
```

The associations have not changed (users belong to client, client has many users). This now seems to be the problem with every association of this kind.

Do we now really have to change all these where queries so that they use the foreign_key or is there any other way?

rails version:

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.2.6"
```

mysql2 version:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
```

Comment: Are you sure this was working in 3.0? AFAIK, this is the same behaviour as 3.0.

Comment: You're right. We just found out that a previous developer used a gem called meta_where, which is unfortunately deprecated in Rails 3.1 upwards.

Comment: No problem :)
You could mark your answer as community wiki and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just found out that this functionality was provided by a gem called [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where/), which is deprecated in Rails 3.1+.
There is an alternative, [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel), which unfortunately doesn't provide the exact same syntax. (Or we just haven't found out yet...)
Investigating now...

Thanks @zsquare for pointing out.